# Youtube video events not firing [when testing locally or otherwise]?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have the following code, pretty much taken directly from the API but the events are not firing. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '250',
      width: '300',
      videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    alert("Ready");
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

      alert("State Changed");

  }
```

ANSWERED: Turns out it was because I was testing locally, doh! But see below for other possible causes.

Comment: I too was developing locally.... *facepalm*

Comment: Possible causes:

 1. In some browsers, testing "locally" (loading the file without going through   
    http://localhost)  won't work due to side-effects of security
    restrictions
 2. Mixing Embed API (where you declare an iframe) with iframe API (where you declare a DIV and load some JS). The events only seem to work with the latter.
 3. ID on the DIV does not match ID on new YT.Player(...) call 
 4. Failing to define `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` at a global scope

I'm glad the OP only had issue #1. I had to get through all four to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the code below, works perfectly for me

```js
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
//Load player api asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
      playerVars:{'autoplay':1, 'rel':0, 'showinfo':0, 'egm':0, 'showsearch':0,},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event,element) {
    //When the video has ended
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        //Get rid of the player
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```